# Bode plot of the open loop given the state space - SIMO

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have a SIMO system. $\xi$ is the input and $Y$ is the output. The state space model is given by

\begin{align}
\dot{X} &= AX + B\xi\\
y&=r-Cx
\end{align}

$A$ is $5 \times 5$ matrix. $B$ is $5 \times 1$. The controller $K$ is a state feedback controller such that $A - BK$ is Hurwitz. The schematic overview is shown in the figure. How can I find out the **open loop** or **closed loop** bandwidth for this system?

Edit: By bandwidth I mean the frequency at which the open loop transfer function crosses the $0$dB line.

Edit2: Maybe the question wasn't very clear. After I design the feedback control law, my system is
\begin{equation}
\dot{X} = (A - BK)X
\end{equation}

Now the transfer function is essentially from reference $r$ to a chosen output $y$. But given $A-BK$, how do I find the transfer function? Note that the feedback is a state feedback and hence is very difficult to write as a transfer function.

Comment: How is $Y$ calculated? Normally in state space as follows, $Y=C\,X+D\,\xi$. Normally for a state space model with an observer based controller you first estimate the full state with $\dot{\hat{X}}=A\hat{X}+B\xi+L(Y-D\xi-C\hat{X})$ and $\xi=-K\hat{X}$, where $L$ and $K$ can be designed by you, such that $A-BK$ and $A-LC$ are Hurwitz matrices. Also do you know if your state space model is minimal (controllable and observable)?

Comment: Sorry I have reformulated the question because it was formulated badly...So I have already designed the feedback controller that makes the system Hurwitz. Point is I was to find out the open-loop and closed-loop bandwidth of the system.

Comment: Well, the bandwidth gives an estimate of the frequency range for which the control input is effective. Since you have a SIMO system you can use instead of $|G(j\omega_B)|=1$ (which you have used for the SISO system) the condition $\sigma_{\min}(G(j\omega_B))=1$ where $\sigma_{\min}$ denotes the smallest singular value. In fact, in this case, this is equivalent to $\|G(j\omega_B)\|^2=G^H(j\omega_B)G(j\omega)=1$ i.e. $B^T(-j\omega_B-A)^{-T}(j\omega_B-A)^{-1}B=1$ for the open-loop system and similarly for the closed-loop system (replace $A-BK$ instead of $A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a state space model of the following form,

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u, \tag{1}
$$

$$
y = C\,x + D\,u. \tag{2}
$$

The openloop transfer function of this system can be found by taking the Laplace transform and assuming all initial conditions to be zero (such that $\mathcal{L}\{\dot{x}(t)\}$ can just be written as $s\,X(s)$). Doing this for equation $(1)$ yields,

$$
s\,X(s) = A\,X(s) + B\,U(s), \tag{3}
$$

which can be rewritten as,

$$
X(s) = (s\,I - A)^{-1} B\,U(s). \tag{4}
$$

Substituting this into equation $(2)$ and defining the openloop transfer function $G(s)$ as the ratio between output ($Y(s)$) and input ($U(s)$) yields,

$$
G(s) = C\,(s\,I - A)^{-1} B + D. \tag{5}
$$

---

In a normal [block diagram representation](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlFrequency#48) the controller has as an input $r-y$, with $r$ the reference value you would like to have for $y$, and an output $u$, which would be the input to $G(s)$. For now $r$ can be set to zero, so the controller can be defined as the transfer function from $-y$ to $u$.

For an observer based controller ($L$ and $K$ such that $A-B\,K$ and $A-L\,C$ are Hurwitz) for a state space model we can write the following dynamics,

$$
u = -K\,\hat{x}, \tag{6}
$$

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x - B\,K\,\hat{x}, \tag{7}
$$

$$
\dot{\hat{x}} = A\,\hat{x} + B\,u + L(y - C\,\hat{x} - D\,u) = (A - B\,K - L\,C + L\,D\,K) \hat{x} + L\,y. \tag{8}
$$

Similar to equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(5)$, the transfer function of the controller $C(s)$, defined as the ratio of $U(s)$ and $-Y(s)$, can be found to be,

$$
C(s) = K\,(s\,I - A + B\,K + L\,C - L\,D\,K)^{-1} L. \tag{9}
$$

If you want to find the total openloop transfer function from "$-y$" to "$y$" you have to keep in mind that in general $G(s)$ and $C(s)$ are matrices of transfer functions, so the order of multiplication matters. Namely you first multiply the error ($r-y$) with the controller and then the plant, the openloop transfer function can be written as $G(s)\,C(s)$. The closedloop transfer function can then be found with,

$$
\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} = (I + G(s)\,C(s))^{-1} G(s)\,C(s). \tag{10}
$$

It can also be found directly using equations $(2)$ and $(6)$, and the closedloop state space model dynamics,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{\hat{x}}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & -B\,K \\
L\,C & A - B\,K - L\,C
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ \hat{x}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -L
\end{bmatrix} r, \tag{11}
$$

$$
\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} = \begin{bmatrix}
C & -D\,K
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
s\,I - A & B\,K \\
-L\,C & s\,I - A + B\,K + L\,C
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -L
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{12}
$$

Comment: I appreciate the answer....But the portion that relates to my problem is when I have the feedback already designed, then my input-output relation is from $r$ to $y$. You are right. But I do not see how I have the transfer function now?

Comment: @Zero $G(s)$, $C(s)$ and $\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}$ are all (matrices of) transfer functions.

Comment: Yeah you are right...I just asked the question wrong...I wanted to ask a general question to confirm my method but I think I messed up the question. Still given the question your answer is right. You can always treat the system as multivariable (Postlethwaite). I'll accept the answer given the question :)